# 'Could not launch simulator for iphonesimulator .. Unable to boot the Simulator '

Tags: xcode

when run project at code 9.4 get black iphoen screen and error message
 'Could not launch simulator for iphonesimulator.
Unable to boot the Simulator.'

Comment: Interesting. So what's your **question**?

Comment: I need soulatiin for this error to can simulate.